# C++ Template: what does this ... mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I met a piece of code below and get lost:

```
template<typename T>
T add(T t, T u)
{
    return t + u;
}

template<typename ... T>
std::vector<int> add_values(int value, T ... t)
{
    return{ add(t, value)... }; //what does this ... mean?
} 

int main()
{
    add_values(4); 

    return 0;
}
```

I can understand that the `typename ... T` means a series of types, and `T ... t` means a series of `T1 t1`, `T2 t2` .... parameters. But what does the `...` in the `return{ add(t, value)... }` line mean?

Comment: Look for "variadic template" and parameter pack expansion

Comment: It means `return { add(t1, value), add(t2, value), ...};` just as you'd expect.

Comment: @Barmar hmmm... so what is the data type of `{ add(t1, value), add(t2, value), ...}` ? this is not a `std::vector<int>` right?

Comment: Yes, it's a `std::vector<int>`, since that's the return type of your function.

Comment: @Barmar OK, let me check it out.

Comment: It's initializer_list used for returned vector constructor

Comment: @KIIV thank you, let me google that.